# Does the condition ${(n +1)^2} |x_n - x_{n+1}| \to 0$ imply that $\lim x_n$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following condition imply the convergence of the sequence ${(x_n)}$ ?

Given $ε > 0$ there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbf{N}$ such that $n > n_0$, ${(n +1)^2} |x_n - x_{n+1}| < \epsilon$.

If the question were as follows:

If for an arbitrary $ε > 0$, there exists an $n_0 \in $ **N** such that $n > n_0$.

$$\frac{1}{(n +1)^2}|x_n - x_{n+1}| < ε$$then taking $x_n = n$ suffices the assumption, and it is a non convergent sequence. So the answer would have been in a negation. But I could not find any way for the former case.

Comment: Take $x_n=n^2$. This provides a counter-example to your first statement.

Comment: @frog in fact his counterexample works for his first statement.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I have edited. @llham. Thanx

Comment: If you write the inequality as $$\lvert x_n - x_{n+1}\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{(n+1)^2},$$ does that give you an idea?

Comment: No @ Daniel. The main problem to me is that the terms in the modulus are consecutive.

Comment: It is enough to take $\epsilon=1$. From the convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, show that the sequence $(x_n)$ is  a **Cauchy sequence**.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You mean to say that the terms of the sequence can be taken as $x_n = \sum \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ without loss of generality???

Comment: No, I certainly do not!  More hint. Let $m, n$ be big, with $n\gt m$. Then by the triangle inequality $|x_n-x_m|\le  |x_{m+1}-x_m| +|x_{m+2}=x_{m+1}|+\cdots+|x_n-x_{n-1}|$.  Now use the condition $|x_{k+1}-x_k|$ small if $k$ is big.  Look at the hint of Daniel Fischer.

Comment: Got it @AndréNicolas Thanx...

Comment: You are welcome.  Note that for all $\epsilon$ there is an $n_0$ such that past it we have $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{n+1}$ would not be good enough to prove convergence.

Answer (score 2):

The series $\sum \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ is convergent. Let it converge to a number, say to $S$. Clearly $S > 0$.

Let $ε > 0$ be arbitrary. Then for $\frac{ε}{S}$, by our assumption, there exists an $n_0 \in $ **N** , such that
$|x_n - x_{n + 1}| < \frac{ε}{S}.\frac{1}{(n + 1)^2}$ for all $n > n_0$.

Now by triangle inequality, for $n > n_0$, we have $|x_n - x_{n_0}| \leq |x_n - x_{n - 1}| + |x_{n - 1} - x_{n - 2}| + . . . + |x_{n_0 + 1} - x_{n_0}|$
$$\lt \frac{ε/S}{(n)^2} + \frac{ε/S}{(n - 1)^2} + \frac{ε/S}{(n - 2)^2} + . . . + \frac{ε/S}{(n_0 + 1)^2}
 \leq \frac{ε}{S} \sum \frac{1}{(n)^2} = ε.$$

Thus for an arbitrary $ε > 0$, there exists an $n_0 \in$ **N**, such that

$|x_n - x_{n_0}| \lt ε$ for each $n > n_0$